# Console.log giving error in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

I am newbie to Node. I have installed Node on my nginx server. Created a folder namely test in the root. Inside the test folder I have created a js file namely test.js.

I have written a simple `Console.log("Hi")`.

Now in the terminal I am running the following code:

```
node test.js
```

I am getting following error.

```
/root/test/test.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { console.log("HI...")ø
                                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: console ... not Console - though your actual code seems to use console ... `console.log("HI...")ø` that last character is causing node to choke

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX. That was the error. It's working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a **typo** `ø` after `console.log()`

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.log("Hi")
```

to reference the global console object in Node you need to use lowercase.

Your program would therefore be `console.log("Hi")`

Also, the error suggests you have an extra character after the console statement. Make sure the `ø` character is removed.

Comment: It appears they have used the lower case based on the error

Comment: updated. guess the question itself contains the typo.

Answer (score 1):

(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { console.log("HI...")ø  , there was a typo. ø